# Natural-Language-Processing, Machine Learning, Data Science

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science

How to extract multiple tweets from different twitter accounts with the help of sentiment function. (Use python language, Natural Language Processing)
Create a graph using matplot to represent positive & negative output. Also find the probability and total number of tweets and find the future coming tweets.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You are expected to show some effort towards solving the homework problem yourself before you post here.  Please add what you have already done to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The starting point is for you to collect the data. You can use a Twitter API to get want you need but you can also get a ready dataset from Kaggle and use it to start building your sentiment analysis model. In my opinion, Sentiment analysis is mainly a classification problem so you could use the sklearn library in Python along with nltk for word tokenization. I would suggest to start with the above and when you reach a point that you need help you could update your post with some code so that stack overflow community could provide more specific answers.